# My Darkmode not save in localstorage Svelte

Tags: javascript, local-storage, svelte, darkmode, svelte-store

hello devs I'm trying to save my dark mode in localstorage but I can't I've been trying for hours and I don't see documentation that works for me I'm using svelte not sveltekit
Sorry for my english i'm not a native and sorry for my ask i am new in development and in stackoverflow

```js
// This is my store but not work the localStorage
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';


const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("darkmode");
export let darkmode=writable(storedTheme);
darkmode.subscribe(value => {
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", value===false ? false : true);
});

// and in my switch  archieve i got this
<script>
  import {darkmode} from '../store/Store';
    const handleClick=()=>{
        darkmode.update(darkmode=>!darkmode);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem` converts the value to a string before storing it. If you do `localStorage.getItem('darkmode')` in the JS console then you'll likely get `"true"` or `"false"` rather than `true` or `false`.

It's hard to know whether this is what's causing your issue without seeing how you are using the value of `darkmode` in your view. If you're treating it like a Boolean, I would expect it to *always* be in dark mode, since the strings `"true"` and `"false"` both convert to the Boolean value `true`.

If this is what's happening, the easiest way to fix it would be with something like this:

```js
const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("darkmode") === "true";
```

More generally, if you want to store non-string values in localStorage then you may want to consider serializing/deserializing them using `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse`. This will handle your Boolean case here, as well as more complicated things like an object.

Comment: Thank you so much yes i trying with boolean your response solve my problem thank dev